# Apex - How can use identify Apex classes that haven't been executed for a while

Tags: salesforce, apex, tooling

I am looking for a way to identity Apex classes/VF Pages that haven't been used for a while to clean up.
Any potential ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can check by **LastModifiedDate** field on apex class, to check which are not touched for a while(most probably not being used).

Use this SOQL:

```
SELECT Name, LastModifiedDate FROM ApexClass ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC
```

On the result on above query you can analyze if you need that class or not.

For VisualForce pages, you can use the below SOQL:

```
SELECT Name, LastModifiedDate FROM ApexPage ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC
```